# $wpdb update multiple rows in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to update multiple rows in wordpress using $wpdb but It doesn't work! Any help would be appreciated!

```
$deps = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  $departments", ARRAY_A);
$deps_var = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT count(*) FROM  $departments");
...
for($i=0;$i<$deps_var;$i++)
    {
    $updatedeps=array(
        'dept_name' => $_POST['dept_name'][$i], 
        'dept_contact_name' => $_POST['dept_contact_name'][$i],
        'dept_contact_email' => $_POST['dept_contact_email'][$i],
        'dept_contact_tel' => $_POST['dept_contact_tel'][$i],
        'dept_contact_fax' => $_POST['dept_contact_fax'][$i], 
        'dept_status' => $_POST['dept_status'][$i],
    ) ;
    $where=array('dept_id' => $_POST['dept_id'][$i] );
    $wpdb->update( $departments, $updatedeps, $where);
    }

<?php foreach ( $deps as $dep ) { ?>
       <tr>
        <td><input name="dept_id[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_id'] ?>" class="form-control" disabled></td>
        <td><input name="dept_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_name'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="dept_contact_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_name'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="dept_contact_email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_email'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="dept_contact_tel[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_tel'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="dept_contact_fax[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_fax'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="dept_status[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_status'] ?>" class="small-text"></td>
      </tr> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is stored in $departments?

Comment: $departments=$wpdb->prefix.'departments';

Comment: are you getting values in your $deps and $deps_var?

Comment: I've got 2 rows in deps, so value 2 in deps_var

Comment: The second loop works fine, it display 2 results... but when I try to update them - doesn't

Comment: can you set the wp_debug  to true and see if you are getting any errors or not?

Comment: you mean your values are not updating in front table??  have you checked in db ?

Comment: I checked but no results. I'm trying to debug

Comment: can you show the full code of your form?

Comment: Undefined index: dept_id on line : $where=array('dept_id' => $_POST['dept_id'][$i] );

Comment: check the db for the column name of dept_id also check the value of $_POST['dept_id'][$i].

Comment: Remove  "disabled" from the first input and make it read only. disabled inputs are not considered in form submit so you will not  get the value of dept_id.

Comment: Thanks man, disabled was the problem :) Saved my life! Thanks again !

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote my answer. as another answer is already accepted.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder it's get an undefined array index error since you set the `dept_id` input disabled. In order to preserve the `dept_id` values, you could setup a hidden `dept_id` input after the disabled input :

```
<?php foreach ( $deps as $dep ) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_id'] ?>" class="form-control" disabled></td>
    <td><input name="dept_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_id'] ?>" ></td>
    <td><input name="dept_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_name'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input name="dept_contact_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_name'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input name="dept_contact_email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_email'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input name="dept_contact_tel[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_tel'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input name="dept_contact_fax[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_contact_fax'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input name="dept_status[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_status'] ?>" class="small-text"></td>
  </tr> <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have **"disabled"** property in 
`<td><input name="dept_id[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_id'] ?>" class="form-control" disabled></td>`
disabled inputs are not considered in form submit. change it to **read only**